# JavaScript - browser detection for iOS/Android touch devices

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, cross-browser

I have the following JavaScript code that utilises browser detection and `navigator.platform` property and the `navigator.userAgent` property of the navigator object. This is used to execute environment/platform specific code based on what device an end user is browsing on.

The issue stemmed from the behaviour of Bootstrap tooltips on Android and iOS devices - the tooltips appears when the user hovers over an `<a>` element, now touch devices have no concept of hover and do not handle it well (for example on iOS using Safari the tooltips are not able to be dismissed after the first touch, on Android using Chrome the tooltip is visible for a split second). The decision was made that tooltip functionality should not be available to users on mobile devices, as they are not handled well.

The issue is visible here on the `<a>` elements (a tooltip is **intentionally**  applied to the iOS and Android code blocks to demo issue) used as links with an icon that read 'Disco', 'Bouncy Castles', 'Clowns' etc. (if viewed on a phsyical iOS or Android tablet above 768px): http://fun-booths.co.uk/dev/

[image]

HTML (one fragment)

```
    <span class="dec-block hidden-xs"> 
      <span class="promo-details">   
      <i class ="fa fa-headphones"> </i>
      <span class="promo-a-cont">  
      <a href="http://www.bestdiscointown.co.uk" title="" class="customtooltip" data-original-title="Best Disco in Town offer a professional DJ suitable for any party."> 
       <span class="dashed"> Disco </span>
      </a>
      </span>
    </span>
```

JS

As you can see the code says if `isOS` tests true then don't execute the tooltip JavaScript, the `else if` statement then checks if `isAndroid` tests true and again no tooltip JavaScript is executed. Finally an `else` statement says if the users is on any other system then execute the tooltip JavaScript.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var isOS = /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.platform);
  var isAndroid = /(android)/i.test(navigator.userAgent);

  ///////////////////////////////////////// if OS
  if (isOS){

  ///////////////////////////////////////// if Android
  } else if(isAndroid){

  ///////////////////////////////////////// if another system
  } else {
    toolOptions = {
      animation: true,
      placement:"top",
      template: '<div class="tooltip" role="tooltip"><div class="tooltip-arrow"></div><div class="tooltip-inner"></div></div>',
      container:"body"
    };

    $('.customtooltip').tooltip(toolOptions);

  }//end if system
});
```

I need to increase my understanding of this issue and potential solutions, so please if you can answer my questions.

1. Is the navigator object a native JavaScript object like the date object is?
2. If the navigator object is native, then am I correct in saying this is surely built in to all modern web browsers as they have a JavaScript engine? So why is this considered a bad practice?
3. After performing research on MDN - the `navigator.platform` property and the `navigator.userAgent` are stated as:

> 'This feature has been removed from the Web standards. Though some
>   browsers may still support it, it is in the process of being dropped.
>   Do not use it in old or new projects. Pages or Web apps using it may
>   break at any time.'

and:

> Browser identification based on detecting the user agent string is
>   unreliable and is not recommended, as the user agent string is user
>   configurable.

Given that this approach of browser detection does not abide by web standards how can I prevent tooltips being displayed to the user on touch devices?

4. I have tested this on multiple versions of real Android tablets and iOS tablets and this JavaScript fix does work - even though it is bad practice. The popovers do not appear and therefore I consider the issue to be fixed. However are there other touch device scenarios I haven't considered outside of Android and iOS devices.

Comment: Browser sniffing gets abused much more than it gets used properly. `if  (browser!="my favourite browser") tell user(they are idiots)`